# Unit testing with AspectJ in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm developing an application which uses AspectJ with Java. In development, I use ajc and java together. AspectJ calls some code segments when necessary and I want to test these code segments called by AspectJ. I tried to do it with Mockito but I failed, does anyone know any other way to test it?

Comment: Maybe you can try this: https://github.com/david-888/aspectj-junit-runner

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure on how to do it in plain **Java** and **JUnit**, but if you have access to **Spring-Integration-Test** you can have an easy approach with the **MockMVC** and support classes that it offers.

And bellow you can see an example in which I am testing a controller that has an **Aspect** wrapped around it:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
public class ControllerWithAspectTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private MongoController mongoController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
        // if you want to inject mocks into your controller
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testControllerWithAspect() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mockMvc
                .perform(
                        MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/my/get/url")
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn();
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
    static class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public MongoAuditingAspect getAuditingAspect() {
            return new MongoAuditingAspect();
        }

    }

}
```

You can use the approach above even if you don't have **Spring** configured in your application, as the approach I've used will allow you to have a configuration class (can and should be a public class residing in it's own file).

And if the `@Configuration` class is annotated with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`, **Spring** will know that it needs to enable aspects in your test/application.

If you need any extra clarification I will provide it with further edits.

**EDIT:**

The Maven Spring-Test dependency is:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well, I'm not into Spring framework but I tried your way. First, spring-webmvc is needed as another dependency because WebAbblicationContext cannot be imported. Even then, there is no MongoAuditingAspect class. As I said, I'm not very into Spring framework so these can be dummy classes, I don't know. I appreciate the help but when I have nothing to do with Spring, I expect to find a nice way to test the code :)

Comment: MongoAuditingAspect  was an example of an aspect :) sorry mate i forgot to say that

Answer (score 2):

I just created a JUnit4 Runner to allow AspectJ Load Time Weaving on JUnit test cases. Here is a simple example:

I created a HelloService to return a greeting. And I created an Aspect to make names in the greeting upper case. Finally i created a unit test to use the HelloService with a lower case name and expect an upper case result.

All the details of the example are part of the GitHub project for reference:
https://github.com/david-888/aspectj-junit-runner

Just include the most up to date [aspectj-junit-runner JAR](https://github.com/david-888/aspectj-junit-runner/dist) in your classpath. Then your tests may look like this:

```
@AspectJConfig(classpathAdditions = "src/test/hello-resources")
@RunWith(AspectJUnit4Runner.class)
public class HelloTest {

    @Test
    public void getLiveGreeting() {
        String expected = "Hello FRIEND!";
        HelloService helloService = new HelloService();
        String greeting = helloService.sayHello("friend");
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, greeting);
    }

}
```